# Selenium JS: Stripe paymet: Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:63506

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I wrote this script to run on my site. It supposed to fill out some form then press the payment button and after that, it'll wait for the Stripe payment page then fill out the card info and proceed further.

But the problem is automation work on my site end when it hit the payment button and go to Stripe end, automation stop working and throw this error,

> Error: ECONNREFUSED connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:49383
> at ClientRequest. (//node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:273:15)
>
> (node:61074) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: ECONNREFUSED
> connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:49383
> at ClientRequest. (//node_modules/selenium-webdriver/http/index.js:273:15)
>
> (node:61074) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise
> rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async
> function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was
> not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 2) (node:61074) [DEP0018]
> DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In
> the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
> Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Script:

```
const {Builder, Key, By, Capabilities} = require('selenium-webdriver');
(async function makeDonation() {
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();
 
        await driver.get('<URL>');
        // step 2 - fill out the form and proceed
        await driver.findElement(By.css('#support > div > div > div > form > div:nth-child(1) > input')).sendKeys('Test');
        await driver.findElement(By.css('#support > div > div > div > form > div:nth-child(2) > input')).sendKeys('test@test.com');
        await driver.findElement(By.css('#support > div > div > div > form > div:nth-child(3) > textarea')).sendKeys('Test', Key.TAB);
        await driver.sleep(500);
        await driver.findElement(By.css('<element>')).click();
        // step 3 - agree to pay
        let title_1 = await driver.getTitle();
        console.log(title_1);
        await driver.sleep(1000);
        await driver.findElement(By.css('#body > div.ReactModalPortal > div > div > div > div.d-flex.flex-column.justify-content-center.p-5 > form > button')).click();
        // step 4 - fill out the payment info on Stripe
        await driver.sleep(5000);
        const value = await driver.getTitle();
        console.log(value);
        await driver.findElement(By.css('#email')).sendKeys('email@email.com');
        await driver.findElement(By.css('#cardNumber')).sendKeys('4242424242424242');
        await driver.findElement(By.css('#cardExpiry')).sendKeys('0125');
        await driver.findElement(By.css('#cardCvc')).sendKeys('000');
        await driver.findElement(By.css('#billingName')).sendKeys('Name');
        await driver.findElement(By.css('#root > div > div > div.App-Payment > div > form > div:nth-child(2) > div:nth-child(4) > button > div.SubmitButton-IconContainer')).click();
        // final step - Expect the success page
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    } finally {
        driver.quit();
    }
})();
```

Note: from beginning to step 3 it just works fine. When it starts executing step 4, it stops working.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved:** I have run Chromedriver in headless mode and found out the issue is solved

```
const {Builder, Key, By, Capabilities} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const chromeCapabilities = Capabilities.chrome();
chromeCapabilities.set('chromeOptions', {args: ['--headless']});
let driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').withCapabilities(chromeCapabilities).build();
```